# How to integrate javascript code in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to AngularJS and I am experimenting with particular javascript file which I am trying to integrate into the angularJS.

my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://docs.handsontable.com/0.16.1/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"src="https://docs.handsontable.com/0.16.1/bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://docs.handsontable.com/0.16.1/bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.min.css">
</head>

<body >

<div id="example1" class="hot handsontable htRowHeaders htColumnHeaders" dragResize></div>
</body>

</html>
```

My app.js

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).directive('dragResize',function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'EA',
        controller: function($scope, $timeout){
            //document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  var
    container = document.getElementById('example1'),
    hot;

  hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    data: Handsontable.helper.createSpreadsheetData(200, 10),
    rowHeaders: true,
    colHeaders: true,
    colWidths: [55, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80],
    rowHeights: [50, 40, 100],
    manualColumnResize: true,
    manualRowResize: true
  });

  function bindDumpButton() {
      if (typeof Handsontable === "undefined") {
        return;
      }

      Handsontable.Dom.addEvent(document.body, 'click', function (e) {

        var element = e.target || e.srcElement;

        if (element.nodeName == "BUTTON" && element.name == 'dump') {
          var name = element.getAttribute('data-dump');
          var instance = element.getAttribute('data-instance');
          var hot = window[instance];
          console.log('data of ' + name, hot.getData());
        }
      });
    }
  bindDumpButton();
    $timeout(dragResize,0);
//});
        }

    };
});
```

I am not sure whether I am doing it right. I tried to run the file but it displayed nothing. I have couple of queries:-
1. How to call the controller in my index.html?
2. Is there the better way to embed the javascript file?
3. Which would be better choice creating a factory and exposing the dependency or creating custom directive?

Would appreciate some knowledge sharing on the problem.

thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Angular is two way binding. So you don't need to inflate any view say DIV with id example1 in your code.

You can create scope to reflect your output using $scope or $rootScope.

And If you want to do this using document.getElementById("") then better go with normal js file instead controller in AngularJS.

And as you have asked :: MultiController in index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
            First Name:
            <input type="text" ng-model="firstName">
            <br> Last Name:
            <input type="text" ng-model="lastName">
            <br>
            <br> Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}
        </div>
        <div ng-controller="myCtrl2">
            First Name:
            <input type="text" ng-model="firstName2">
            <br> Last Name:
            <input type="text" ng-model="lastName2">
            <br>
            <br> Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.firstName = "John";
        $scope.lastName = "Doe";
    });

    app.controller('myCtrl2', function($scope) {
        $scope.firstName2 = "asdf";
        $scope.lastName2 = "asdfdsf";
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No I want to use AngularJS only. And I am looking for alternatives to change/integrate existing javascript code into angularjs code.

Comment: You can use document.getElementById() in Angularjs, but manipulating HTML in a controller is not a good practice.

I recommend you to [create](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) a directive and do this kind of stuff there.